# Does Evernote's b64dec.py script convert all types (txt, pdf, jpg etc.)

Tags: python, evernote

Learning Python, I found Evernote's python script [b64dec.py](https://gist.github.com/evernotegists/6134552) for converting notes described in an .ENEX file back to their native format.

I was unclear how it even worked at first.  I could not find a "cat" command for example. (Line 27 in github listing)

```
# cat base64File | python b64dec.py myfile.ext
```

I concluded eventually you invoke it with :

```
<source ENEX file> | python b64dec.py <outputfile.desired_extension >
```

Is that correct?

I have tried sending a text only note to a .txt file, and an image only note to a .jpg file.  They all end up zero length files.

Am I invoking this script correctly. Do I understand its purpose correctly (converts a note with an image back to an image etc.).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Copyright 2013 Evernote Corporation. All rights reserved.

import base64
import sys

# Copy the base64 string from the ENEX file and put it into a file

# Pipe base64-encoded data to STDIN
data = sys.stdin.read()

# Decode data
try:
    imgraw = base64.b64decode(data)
except TypeError, te:
    print 'TypeError: ', te
    raise SystemExit

# Write it to the file passed as a param
with file(sys.argv[1], 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(imgraw)

## Usage:
## (Change myfile.ext to the desired filename and correct extension)

# cat base64File | python b64dec.py myfile.ext

## or, if you base64 data is in the pasteboard on a Mac:

# pbpaste | python b64dec.py myfile.ext
```

Comment: "I concluded ... `<source ENEX file>`". What happened with the `cat`? That "prints" the contents of the file to the standard output, and the script picks it up from there because of the pipe `|`.

Comment: I was getting "'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I have a fresh install of Python27.

Comment: You must not be on a Linux type shell. Are you on Windows? If so, you can try `type <filename>`, as it does what `cat` does on \*ix systems.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows. and I did figure out to skip typing "cat" and going right to starting the command line with filename.

Comment: I was sending the entire .enex file (an .xml file) through the process.  Last night I had the thought maybe it expects only the data portion of the file, so I stripped out everything. It ran without an error but generated another zero length file.